# Generate random names by geogaphic location

Tags: python, names

**Background.**

When using using honeypots i usually seed them with (fake) data that (i.e. Email addresses, CC information etc.). To create fake identities, accounts and email addresses to seed the honeypots with i'll normally use the `names` module in python. This works excellent to generate very generic names but, afaik, it does not allow for generating country specific names.

**Question.**

Apart from generating a country specific list of names and reading this from my python scripts, where can i find a python friendly module that is capable of doing this?

Comment: have you already used https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html# ?

Comment: never tried it but, it looks promising.
thank you

Comment: @PRMoureu
That was **exactly** what i was looking for.
+1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `faker` as suggested by @PRMoureu i found how to generate country specific names. Can't believe i missed this.

Here's the documentation that shows exactly what i was looking for:
https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html#localization